# Problemas con Cloud Firestore

Tags: angular, ionic, google-cloud-firestore

Estimados tengo un problema con la base de datos de Cloud Firestore de google hace menos de 2 semanas vengo teniendo problemas en mi app ionic angular con el consumo de datos (internet). El consumo se eleva mucho pasando los 4 GB diarios. No se que puede ser, estuve leyendo y quizas es porque Cloud Firestore paso de beta a una version pro. ojala me pudieran ayudar amigos.

```
    this.afs.firestore .doc('personas/') .get(source) .then((snapshot) => 
{
 this.loader.dismiss(); if (snapshot.exists) 
{
 this.afs.firestore .collection('asistencia') .doc(this.selectedPlanta) .collection(this.fechahoy) .where('DNI', '==', RUT_PERSONAL.toUpperCase()) .get({ source: 'default' }) .then((documentSnapshot) => { }).catch(err => { }); } else { } }) .catch((error) => { this.loader.dismiss(); if (error.code == 'unavailable') { } else { } });
```

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos como haces traes los datos? Suena a que mantienes las suscripciones abiertas.

Comment: this.afs.firestore
.doc('personas/')
.get(source)
.then((snapshot) => {
 this.loader.dismiss();
if (snapshot.exists) {
   this.afs.firestore
.collection('asistencia')
  .doc(this.selectedPlanta)
  .collection(this.fechahoy)
  .where('DNI', '==', RUT_PERSONAL.toUpperCase())
  .get({ source: 'default' })
  .then((documentSnapshot) => {     
           
           }).catch(err => {
       
      });
  } else {    
   }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       this.loader.dismiss();
     if (error.code == 'unavailable') {
       } else {
       }
    });

Comment: Edita tu respuesta y coloca el codigo alli, debidamente identado, por favor. En un comentario el codigo que has puesto es ilegible. Asi nos haces dificil ayudarte.

Comment: ahi te respondi amigo quedo atento a tus comentarios.

Comment: `this.afs.firestore
.doc('personas/')
.get(source)
.then((snapshot) => {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        this.afs.firestore
            .collection('asistencia')
            .doc(this.selectedPlanta)
            .collection(this.fechahoy)
            .where('DNI', '==', RUT_PERSONAL.toUpperCase())
            .get({ source: 'default' })
            .then((documentSnapshot) => {

            }).catch(err => {});
    } else {
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    if (error.code == 'unavailable') {
    } else {
    }
});`

Comment: favor ayuda amigo necesito saber el porque si fuera algun problema de programacion siempre estaria ese problema pero hace dos semanas que esto ocurre el sistema lleva como 5 meses en funcionamiento.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afs.firestore
.doc('personas/')
.get(source)
.then((snapshot) => {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        this.afs.firestore
            .collection('asistencia')
            .doc(this.selectedPlanta)
            .collection(this.fechahoy)
            .where('DNI', '==', RUT_PERSONAL.toUpperCase())
            .get({ source: 'default' })
            .then((documentSnapshot) => {

            }).catch(err => {

            });
    } else {
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    if (error.code == 'unavailable') {
    } else {
    }
});
```